# Relation between the mean value inequality over an area and over a surface

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Suppose that $f$ is a locally integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$  $(N\geq2)$ such that for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$  and all positive real number $r$ we have
\begin{equation}
f(x)\leq \frac{1}{|\partial B(x,r)|}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}f(y)d\sigma, \tag{1}
\end{equation} where $B(x,r)$ is the ball of center $x$ and radius $r$.
We know that by taking the integral of both sides with respect to $r$ from $0$ to $R$ we get
\begin{equation}
f(x)\leq \frac{1}{| B(x,R)|}\int_{ B(x,R)}f(y)d\lambda;  \tag{2}
\end{equation}
that is (1) implies (2). My question is: if $f$ satisfies (2), can we coclude that $f$ also satisfies (1)? In another words, does (2) also imply (1)? Why?
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: "...in *other* words..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken literally, property (2) does not imply (1). Indeed, let $f(x)=-1$ if $|x|=1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then (2) holds but (1) fails for $x=0$ and $r=1$.

But generally, one considers locally integrable functions up to equivalence a.e. And property  (2) implies that $f$ agrees a.e. with a [subharmonic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subharmonic_function), for which (1) holds by definition. Here are the steps of the proof.

1. Convolve $f$ with a  radially symmetric decreasing [bump function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).
2. Observe that the new function $f_\epsilon$ still satisfies (2), and is smooth.
3. Using the second-order Taylor formula for $f_\epsilon$, conclude that $\Delta f_\epsilon\ge 0$.
4. Let $\epsilon\to 0$. Then $f_\epsilon\to f$ in $L^1$ (on compact subsets). Consequently, for every nonnegative compactly supported function $\varphi$ we have 
   $$\int f\Delta \varphi = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int f_\epsilon \Delta \varphi = 
   \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int \varphi \Delta f_\epsilon \ge 0\tag{1}$$
5. Thus, $\Delta f$ is a  nonnegative distribution, i.e., a measure. It follows that $f$ agrees almost everywhere with a subharmonic function. Indeed, convolving $\Delta f$ with the fundamental solution $-|\cdot |^{2-N}$ (or $\log |\cdot|$ if $N=2$) we get a subharmonic function $g$  with the same generalized Laplacian. The difference $f-g$ is harmonic in the sense of distributions, and therefore agrees with a classically harmonic function a.e., by Weyl's Lemma.

Let $\tilde f$ be the subharmonic function with which $f$ agrees a.e. Let $N=\{f\ne \tilde f\}$, this is a set of measure zero. Theorems of Stein and Bourgain on the [spherical maximum function](http://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/soria/DOC/DOCTORADO/Notes_section2.pdf) imply that the spherical maximum function of $\chi_N$ is zero almost everywhere. This means: for almost every point $a$, *every* sphere centered at $a$ meets $N$ in a set of spherical measure zero. Consequently, (1) holds for $f$ almost everywhere.

Comment: But since $f$ is not subharmonic, and only locally integrable, the convergence in 4. holds a.e. Isn't it possible to have the inequality everywhere? By the way, is the convergence in 4. is decreasing, even if $f$ is only locally integrable?

Comment: But (2) steel holds $almost$  $everywhere$, no?

Comment: @user127474 Yes, but this relies on a quite subtle fact: see the edit.

Comment: @user127474 Sorry, after rewriting the answer the first time I left in $\searrow$. Should have been $\to$. One can show that $f_\epsilon \ge f$ for every $\epsilon$ (using the assumption about averages over balls), but monotonicity of convergence requires subharmonicity, which is what we are trying to prove. In any event, $L^1$ convergence was all I needed.